# How to convert date into gmt in java

Tags: java

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'SSSX");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println("Current date and time in GMT: " + df.format("2017-01-04"));
```

The above is my code and when I try to convert the date to `gmt` I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot
>   format given Object as a Date     at
>   java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:310)  at
>   java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)  at
>   Sample.main(Sample.java:24)

Please point out what am I doing wrong.

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'SSSX");
 df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
 System.out.println("Current date and time in GMT: " + df.format(new Date()));
```

This above code is working fine but I need something that works for any date.

And when I try this code:

```
try {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'SSSX");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    System.out.println("Current date and time in GMT: " + df.parse("2017-01-04"));

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting `Unparseable date: "2017-01-04"`. Please tell me how to fix it

Comment: What exactly is the complete use case? You prefer to convert the server / host time to GMT? Or building a converter which converts between time zones? or what else? df.format method accepts Date object and not String.

Comment: For your latest edit - modify the first line to DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); and you should be able to parse

Comment: please check my query i  need date like  2017-01-04T101Z in GMT format

Comment: S corresponds to milliseconds (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) - do you need milliseconds value ignoring hours, minutes and seconds?

Comment: yes please help me in this

Comment: Is your source timezone fixed? I mean if your code runs on a different machine in a different geo, the corresponding timezone can be picked up. There are timezones ahead of GMT and there are the ones behind GMT. A clear explanation would help.

Comment: what we do we are getting data in GMT format then we are converting in IST format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132281/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-and-maklee-lee).

Answer (score 3):

Try it..

```
String s = "2016-11-21 13:30:0.0";
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss);
        Date d = null;
        try 
        {
            d = format.parse(s);
        } catch (ParseException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SimpleDateFormat gmtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'SSSX");

        gmtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

        System.out.println(gmtFormat.format(d));
```

Comment: 2016-11-21 13:30:00.0  my date is coming like this now i am using ur Code  then i am getting 2017-01-03T18:30:00Z  which i wrong

Comment: please suggest me

Comment: `gmtFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));` - solution. Should be marked as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you have a date object then you can format it as you want:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

//create a calendar representing your date.
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(2017, 01, 04);

//format the date object to the pattern you want.
String DateToStr = format.format(cal.getTime());

System.out.println(DateToStr);
```

If you have your date as string you can also do:

```
String string = "2017-01-04";
DateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
format1.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
Date date = null;
try {
    date = format1.parse(string);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: my date is in String @paner

Comment: Just include the timezone in the SDF and your answer looks fine.

Comment: Wed Jan 04 00:00:00 IST 2017  its coming in IST while i need  2017-01-04T101Z like this

Comment: @Paner plz suggest me Solution

Comment: You have the correct date now how to format it is at the first code snippet in my answer also see the examples https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

The below code is to help in understanding better - you can try uncommenting the commented lines and compare the results. The point of interest for you in this whole block is `gdf.parse(gmtFormat)`

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat idf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    idf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
    DateFormat gdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    gdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));

    //String istFormat = idf.format(date);
    //System.out.println("IST: "+istFormat);

    String gmtFormat = gdf.format(date);
    System.out.println("GMT: "+ gmtFormat);
    try {
        //System.out.println("gmt parsed from istFormat: "+gdf.parse(istFormat));
        //System.out.println("ist parsed from istFormat: "+idf.parse(istFormat));

        System.out.println("gmt parsed from gmtFormat: "+gdf.parse(gmtFormat));
        System.out.println("ist parsed from gmtFormat: "+idf.parse(gmtFormat));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```